# Можно ли определить браузер, ОС, IP и прочую информацию о пользователе используя Flask

Tags: python, flask

Можно ли как нибудь определить IP-адрес пользователя, ОС, браузер, и.т.д используя Flask?

Comment: Можно... ОС и браузер из заголовка `User-Agent`, `ip` — `request.remote_addr`, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: хорошо, благодаю за ответ